# Why Isn't My Jumping Frame Rate Independent in My 2D Unity Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some reason I jump at a different height according to frame rate. Why is this happening even though I am using delta time to(try) make it frame rate independant. This is in 2D in case ye needed to know.

```
void Jump()
{
    // Set Delta Time(Time Between Frames)
    float dT = Time.deltaTime;
    // Counting In Seconds
    secondForGravity += dT;
    // Check For Input and Jump
    if (canJump && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        // Add Jump Height to Velocity
        velocity.y += jumpHeight;
        // Reset Can Jump
        canJump = false;
        // Resets Second For Gravity to 0 so You Can't Fall 
        secondForGravity = 0;
    }
    // Fall With Gravity
    if (!canJump)
    {
        if(velocity.y > 0)
        {
            // Rising Metres Per Second * Per Second & Make it Frame Rate Independent
            velocity.y -= riseGravity * secondForGravity * dT;
        }
        else if(velocity.y < 0)
        {
            // Falling Metres Per Second * Per Second & Make it Frame Rate Independent
            velocity.y -= fallGravity * secondForGravity * dT;
            // Sets Velocity.y To Max Gravity if Exceeding Max Gravity
            if (velocity.y < -maxGravity)
                velocity.y = -maxGravity;
        }
        else
        {
            // Rising Metres Per Second * Per Second & Make it Frame Rate Independent
            velocity.y -= riseGravity * secondForGravity * dT;
        }
    }
}

void Move()
{
    // Move
    rb.AddForce(velocity, ForceMode2D.Force);
}
```

I was wondering if there was anyway I could fix it.

Answer (score 0):

What you’re doing with `secondForGravity` doesn’t seem to make sense. The effect of gravity will become stronger and stronger as `secondForGravity` is increased each frame.

It looks to me as if you should take it out completely and just multiply by deltaTime which represents the fraction of a second that passed since the previous frame (i.e. `1 * deltaTime` should come out to 1 per second apart from slight floating point imprecision).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by adding `velocity` to my current position and using this code in the `Move()` function:

`rb.MovePosition(velocity + new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y));`

Instead of this code:

`rb.AddForce(velocity, ForceMode2D.Force);`

Now whatever frame rate my game is running at the character is moving at a constant pace. I am still usuing the